# WebSphere unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, websphere

I've got a WebSphere 9 server for testing web apps on my laptop. I also have Hybris running under Tomcat on my laptop (for testing also). I wrote a Java web app to test punchout functions in Hybris, that runs on my WebSphere server. It had been working, but I had to reinstall WebSphere. Since then, when I try to run my web app in WebSphere, I get this error in WebSphere:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path
>   building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable
>   to find valid certification path to requested target

whenever my app tries to post to Hybris.

In the administrative console of WebSphere, I used the "receive from port" button to get the self-signed certificate from Hybris into the nodedefaultTrustStore in WebSphere. Hybris is at applied.local:9002 on my laptop and the certificate looks like this:

> CN=applied.local, OU=applied.local, O=applied.local, L=applied.local,
>   ST=WI, C=us  Valid from Jul 17, 2019 to Apr 11, 2022.

All of this was working previously, but I must have broken something. I must be missing something. I don't understand why it can't "find a valid certification path" to applied.local, since the CN is applied.local, and the certificate is in the trust store in WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, but I don't know why I had to do this to get it working. If someone can explain why - that would be great. Anyway here's what I did:

1. Added custom variables to WebSphere to define where cacerts was, but default values should have worked, so not sure if this had any effect. In admin console, application servers > server1 > Java and Process Management, process definition, Java Virtual Machine, Customer properties: javax.net.ssl.truststore (path to cacerts in WebSphere), javax.net.ssl.truststoretype jks, and javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword changeit.
2. Used a browser to export the self-signed certificate Hybris was using to a file.
3. Used Ikeyman to import the certificate into cacerts. (There are instructions on how to do this in IBM's pages).
4. Restarted WebSphere and Hybris and posting from WebSphere to Hybris worked again.

What doesn't make sense to me is that I had previously imported the Hybris self-signed certificate using the "Retrieve from port" button in the admin console for the NodeDefaultTrustStore. That used to work, but now apparently I have to import it into cacerts also or instead?

Comment: That's not a good solution as you are overriding WAS SSL settings. It should work as you did before. You should check SSL config, if it points to the correct truststore, maybe that was changed, or some custom outound ssl config was defined.